# How to interpret numerous processes with exact same RAM usage

Tags: process, top, daemon, ram, htop

I have a VM that processes files, parses the information and saves it to a database. I've been monitoring the resource usage and noticed `/usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon`.. Below you see a screenshot of `HTOP`, when connected via ssh. Does **each** of these, as they all have different PIDs, use 124MB of RAM, or do they share it?

[image: HTOP screenshot]